# extract value after decimal

Tags: c++, string

I am taking a double number in a string because i want to extract its value after the decimal part
I found concatenation not working properly here whats wrong with `str2+=str[n-i]` ?

```
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    int flag=0;
    string str2="";
    int n=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(str[n-i]=='.'){
            flag=1;
            break;
        }

        str2+=str[n-i];
        cout<<str2; 

    }
    reverse(str2.begin(),str2.end());
    int m = stoi(str2);
```

Comment: Dare I ask what the point of `flag` is ?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, wouldn't it be easier to do `x-(int)x` (for example)?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood you properly, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801062/c-convert-a-fractional-part-of-a-number-into-integer) someone asked what you are asking.

I thought on doing this:

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double num1=2.323441;
        double num2=num1-(int)num1;
        cout<<num2;
        return 0;
    }
```

> Printing result: 0.323441

But this does not give your expected result, that I think it is: `323441`.

Then I guess there are 2 possible solutions:

**The first**, 'dirty' and easy one is that number you got, multiply it by 10*it's length: If there are 5 decimals, multiply it by 100000. This way, you'll get the `0.323441`converted to `323441`.

**The Second**, as the answer I linked says, use round and power of:

```
int fractional_part_as_int(double number, int number_of_decimal_places) {
    double dummy;
    double frac = modf(number,&dummy);
    return round(frac*pow(10,number_of_decimal_places));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use **[`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)** to convert the `string` to `double`
- Then use **[`std::modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf)** to decompose the floating point value into integral and fractional parts.

Or after having obtained the `double` value, you can just do:

```
double d = fpValue - (long)fpValue;
```